# Copying a Worksheet

Tags: windows, vba, excel, excel-2013

My Excel is trying (VBA) to get data from Access, putting the data into an empty template, Copying the worksheet and saving the file into another path on my hard disk.

Sometimes my script is running without an error, sometimes Excel (vba) is throwing error "runtime 1004". I´ve googled but did not find a solution for my problem.

Excel is given following error:

[image: Pic #1]

[image: Pic #2]

[image: VBA Code - Debbug mode - Line wich throws error]

Someone who can tell me what i´m doing wrong?

Excel 2013, Windows 7 64bit

Comment: where do you have VL_Info set?

Comment: At the top of my code, without a "sub". `Set wsh_VL_Info = DiesDatei.Sheets("Info VL")`

Answer (score 0):

This error may come from trying to copy a very hidden sheet.
Try like this:

```
wsh_VL_Info.Visible = xlSheetVisible
wsh_VL_Info.Copy after:=wsh_VL_Info
```

And for a better code, do not use `ActiveSheet`, but change it following this logic:

```
wsh_VL_Info.Visible = xlSheetVisible
wsh_VL_Info.Copy after:=wsh_VL_Info
wsh_VL_Info.Name = "Info"
```

Edit:

```
Dim wsh_VL_Info as Worksheet
Set wsh_VL_Info = DiesDatei.Sheets("Info VL")
```

within the `Sub`.

Comment: Doesn´t work. Sorry. The problem isnt only the line with `wsh_VL_Info` ... Sometimes he throws the error on `wsh_VL_Brief` and so on ... all of them if there is an `.Copy`

Comment: @KevinLiss - make sure to declare `Set wsh_VL_Info = DiesDatei.Sheets("Info VL")` in the SUB. it should work.

Comment: thanks for answer, but that doenst work. VBA throws the error `"File not found: 'C:\temp\VBD349.tmp'`. Like always, but not every time i´m using the script ...